# Automatically post form with onclick event

Tags: javascript, forms, events, post, onclick

There is a page that shows a button and needs user action to be able to do  some event handlers.

The page handles some of the variables and processing the values:

```
$returnstring .= '<form action="" method="post">';
$returnstring .= '<input type="hidden" name="cost" value='.$cost.' />';
$returnstring .= '<input type="hidden" name="page" value='.$pageid.' />';
$confirm_purchase = esc_attr(get_option('my_confirm_purchase'));
$returnstring .= '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Purchase"  onclick="return confirm(\''.$confirm_purchase.'\')" />';
$returnstring .= '</form>';
```

I need to process this form automatically. I tried `window.onload` and auto submit by referring form id, but it did not work.

The page will be submitting a form automatically and I need to change the `onclick` event automatically, too.

Is there any way that I can handle this issue? 
How can I change the structure without using form ?

Comment: You want to submit the form using JavaScript without user intervention?

Comment: Yes that is what I am struggling for

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use JQuery and try this:

```
$('<form method="post"><input id="test" value="3"></form>').submit();
```

encapsulate your $returnstring into this:

```
$finalstring = "$(".$returnstring.").submit();"
```

This rendered javascript has to executed after the DOM is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //YOUR CODE
});
```

---

.submit() automatically submits a HTML-form upon execution. Test if it works, I just used this in some older intranet applications and it worked.

Comment: Thansk for yours interest. But I could not  understand that how can I trigger return confirm action

Answer (score 0):

You can adding id to form and submit with native javascript.
The important here is change the "name" property for submit input. 
Warning: you action is "", let say you action is self, so, every time the onLoadEvent submit the form the event will fire again. Just need change the action to "confirm" page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function autoSubmit(){
            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        };
    </script>

</head>
<body onload="autoSubmit()">

    <form action="" method="post" id="myForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="cost" value='2500' />
        <input type="hidden" name="page" value='1001' />
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Purchase"  onclick="return confirm('1')" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I  give it a try but it did not work for me. Page loads continuously. 
How can I  set return confirm event as trigger

Comment: You need add a "confirm" page,  or something, and set that how to "action" form.